# Pgpool prevents collecting statistics by pg_stat_user_functions

Tags: postgresql-14, pgpool

I used Postgresql version 14.
I checked using Pgpool-II for failover and connection pooling.
I enabled collecting statistics to fn_stat_user_functions, but when I attached DB to Pgpool, no statistics are added to fn_stat_user_functions.
Why?
TIA